# Is it possible to connect VGA via an converter to an DVI-D port?

Tags: vga, dvi, display-adapter

I have an samsung screen with VGA input. I want to connect to it via an adapter with DVI, because I don't have an VGA port on my videocard. The problem is that I can't find any DVI male to VGA female adaper. I know it has something to do with analog and digital, but I can't get an clear answer from similar questions.

[MY SCREEN](http://www.cnet.com/products/samsung-syncmaster-720n-lcd-monitor-17-series/specs/)

[MY VIDEOCARD](http://www.sapphiretech.com/productdetial.asp?pid=37BE40BB-7273-46B8-9E32-A8C13262ABE9&lang=eng)

Comment: VGA is your monitors input, not output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to connect VGA via an converter to an DVI-D port?

Via an expensive **active** converter: Yes.
Via a cheap simple cable/plug: No

Reason: DVI-D is digital only, while VGA is analog only.
There are some olders DVI interface which output both an analog and a digital signal and for two a cheap plug changer works, but not from digital only to analog only.

Comment: I eventually just bought a VGA to DisplayPort adapter which solved my problems!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is actually very common, in many cases these adaptors are part of the VGA card package. You can find many of them on ebay or Amazon

[image]

This will work on any video card that does DVI-I (digital and analog) on the DVI port, On 2 DVI port cards , usually only 1 has the analog available to it.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DVI-I

Comment: The example in the picture misses the analog pins though.

Comment: lol, true, we would hope the one purchaced for that purpose would though :-)